# _OBJC_CLASS_$_uniMag", referenced from: error in xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, unimag

I'm working on adding an SDK into my project.And I've successfully added it to my project by following the instructions given in the SDK. After that, I need to activate the SDK. To do that I have to Instantiate an object for the .h file(NSObject as a super class) in a view controller.

here my sample code:

```
UniMag.h

#ifndef UniMag_h
#define UniMag_h
@interface UniMag : NSObject
@end
#endif
```

And `UniMagViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   UniMag *unimagReader = [[UniMag alloc] init];
}
```

And When I build the app it was failed and showing the error as

[image]

And the app is building fine without the allocation.
Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Comment: you have added the framework in build phases -> Link binary with Library. right?

Comment: yeah, i added that in the Link binary with Library.

Comment: Do you build the library yourself?

Comment: I'm just using the third party file in my project.